# Unable to get LEFT JOIN working

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a SQL table in the following form:

```
TimeStamp   OeprationID MachineID   MachineOSVersion
xxx           1         MAC1        Vista
xxx           2         MAC2        Linux
xxx           3         MAC2        Linux
xxx           4         MAC3        MACOS
```

With subscription information available as:

```
SubscriptionID  MachineID
SUB1            MAC1
SUB2            MAC2
SUB3            MAC3
SUB3            MAC3
SUB3            MAC3
```

I'd like to use a LEFT JOIN to achieve a table which gives me a result like this:

```
MachineID   MachineOSVersion Subscription
MAC1        Vista            SUB1
MAC2        Linux            SUB2
MAC3        MACOS            SUB3
```

The operations table contains a MachineOSVersion which i'd like to show up along with the machine and subscription details. there are more fields involved but this is only for sample.

EDIT:
A change in the original problem: The subscription table has multiple MachineIDs, for each of those machine MachineIDs, i'd like to lookup in the Operations table and find out the 'latest' MachineOSVersion available. Since machines OS can be upgraded these may change from an older date to the later. Hence the latest have to be picked.

The problem I'm seeing while using a left join is that I see multiple duplicates being generated. Probably because there are many machine machineIDs in the operation table ?

Comment: What is the exact problem? What have you tried that is not working? Why do you want to use a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: What defines the 'latest OS version'? It looks like this is defined by the timestamp?

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your edit

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a regular `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP` the results to get the desired output with an additional subquery on the `INNER JOIN` to ensure you are getting the latest `MachineOSVersion`.

The subquery gets the last `MachineOSVersion` per machine by the greatest `OperationId`, but you could use another field if required, perhaps timestamp.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3b40/1)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MachineTable
    (
      [TimeStamp] VARCHAR(3) ,
      [OperationID] INT ,
      [MachineID] VARCHAR(4) ,
      [MachineOSVersion] VARCHAR(6)
    );

INSERT  INTO MachineTable
        ( [TimeStamp], [OperationID], [MachineID], [MachineOSVersion] )
VALUES  ( 'xxx', 1, 'MAC1', 'Vista' ),
        ( 'xxx', 2, 'MAC2', 'Linux1' ),
        ( 'xxx', 3, 'MAC2', 'Linux2' ),
        ( 'xxx', 4, 'MAC3', 'MACOS' );

CREATE TABLE SubscriptionsTable
    (
      [SubscriptionID] VARCHAR(4) ,
      [MachineID] VARCHAR(4)
    );

INSERT  INTO SubscriptionsTable
        ( [SubscriptionID], [MachineID] )
VALUES  ( 'SUB1', 'MAC1' ),
        ( 'SUB2', 'MAC2' ),
        ( 'SUB3', 'MAC3' ),
        ( 'SUB3', 'MAC3' ),
        ( 'SUB3', 'MAC3' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  st.MachineId ,
        st.SubscriptionId ,
        mt.MachineOSVersion,
        mt.OperationID
FROM    SubscriptionsTable st
INNER JOIN MachineTable mt ON mt.MachineId = st.MachineId 
      AND mt.OperationID = (SELECT MAX(mt2.OperationID) 
                            FROM MachineTable mt2
                            WHERE mt2.MachineId = mt.MachineId)
GROUP BY st.MachineId ,
        st.SubscriptionId ,
        mt.MachineOSVersion,
        mt.OperationID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3b40/1/0)**:

```
| MACHINEID | SUBSCRIPTIONID | MACHINEOSVERSION | OPERATIONID |
|-----------|----------------|------------------|-------------|
|      MAC1 |           SUB1 |            Vista |           1 |
|      MAC2 |           SUB2 |           Linux2 |           3 |
|      MAC3 |           SUB3 |            MACOS |           4 |
```

Comment: Noticed you are using max on operationId, based on the original post you will only have to select distinct values and then sort by timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Oepration.MachineID, Oepration.MachineOSVersion, Subscription.Subscription
FROM Oepration
LEFT JOIN Subscription
  ON Oepration.MachineID = Subscription.MachineID
```

'Oepration' should probably be 'Operation'?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MachineID, MachineOSVersion,       SubscriptionID AS Subscription
FROM Table1name AS op
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2name AS sub
ON sub.MachineID = op.MachineID
ORDER BY MachineID
```

It's important to use LEFT OUTER JOIN as this is more compliant than 'LEFT JOIN' (it's more likely to work across different types of database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Find the `distinct rows` from `Subscription` table then `Left join` the result with the other table.

```
SELECT SubscriptionID,
       MachineOSVersion,
       A.MachineID
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriptionID,
                        MachineID
        FROM   Subscription) A
       LEFT JOIN operation B
              ON A.MachineID = B.MachineID
```

**Update** :

To get the latest row from Operation table. Use `Window function` to get the latest row from `Operation` table.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER (partition BY [TimeStamp], [MachineID] ORDER BY [OeprationID] DESC) rn,
                *
         FROM   operation)
SELECT SubscriptionID,
       MachineOSVersion,
       A.MachineID
FROM  (SELECT [TimeStamp],[OeprationID],[MachineID],[MachineOSVersion]
       FROM   cte
       WHERE  rn = 1) A
      RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT SubscriptionID,MachineID
                  FROM   SubscriptionsTable) B
              ON A.MachineID = B.MachineID
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I ensure that the 'latest' entry from the operations table is picked up ? I always want only one query to be picked up. The current problem is that the FROM clause is already very complicated and I cannot make any changes to that, so the only place to modify is the LEFT JOIN. SO is there anythign i can add there to pick up the 'latest' machineOS form operations ?

Comment: @confusednerd - check now

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution which will always get the latest value

```
SELECT
  st.MachineID,
  st.SubscriptionID
  (SELECT TOP 1 mt.MachineOSVersion FROM MachineTable mt 
   WHERE mt.MachineID = st.MachineID ORDER BY mt.TimeStamp DESC)
FROM
  (SELECT distinct(sti.MachineID),sti.SubscriptionID FROM SubscriptionsTable sti) st;
```

The subquery within the select (query below) will always get the latest version based on the timestamp. This is probally a better way then going after the operation id as the operationid might not always give the correct order (Some distributed databases for example do not guarantee that the primary keys are always fully in the correct order)

```
  (SELECT TOP 1 mt.MachineOSVersion FROM MachineTable mt 
   WHERE mt.MachineID = st.MachineID ORDER BY mt.TimeStamp DESC) 
  -- Gets the latest machine os version of a system, done by 
  -- selecting the last entry based on the timestamp
```

In the FROM table we select distinct machine id's to get rid of any duplicate machine ids.

```
(SELECT distinct(sti.MachineID),sti.SubscriptionID FROM SubscriptionsTable sti) st;
```

Example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f45bc/8).

DDL for the fiddle:
    CREATE TABLE MachineTable
        (
          [TimeStamp] INT,
          [OperationID] INT ,
          [MachineID] VARCHAR(10) ,
          [MachineOSVersion] VARCHAR(10)
        );

```
INSERT  INTO MachineTable
        ( [TimeStamp], [OperationID], [MachineID], [MachineOSVersion] )
VALUES  ( 1415616586, 1, 'MAC1', 'Vista' ),
        ( 1416480586, 2, 'MAC2', 'Linux v1' ),
        ( 1416912586, 3, 'MAC2', 'Linux v2' ),
        ( 1416998987, 4, 'MAC3', 'MACOS' );

CREATE TABLE SubscriptionsTable
    (
      [SubscriptionID] VARCHAR(4) ,
      [MachineID] VARCHAR(4)
    );

INSERT  INTO SubscriptionsTable
        ( [SubscriptionID], [MachineID] )
VALUES  ( 'SUB1', 'MAC1' ),
        ( 'SUB2', 'MAC2' ),
        ( 'SUB3', 'MAC3' ),
        ( 'SUB3', 'MAC3' ),
        ( 'SUB3', 'MAC3' );
```

SQL query for the fiddle:

```
SELECT
  st.MachineID,
  st.SubscriptionID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 mt.MachineOSVersion FROM MachineTable mt WHERE mt.MachineID = st.MachineID ORDER BY mt.TimeStamp DESC)
FROM
  (SELECT distinct(sti.MachineID),sti.SubscriptionID FROM SubscriptionsTable sti) st;
```

Note: DDL was based on the DDL from Tanner.